# HTML max number of <img> elements

Tags: html, image

Anybody know what's the upper limit for how many img elements can be loaded in a given web page? I'm doing some image processing analysis that I'm presenting in the browser but the page keeps crashing until I trim it down to more limited figures. This may be a function of the image size as well, which in my case is a bunch of 500x500 images. I'll wind up doing a pagination solution but it would be nice to max out the page lengths at the same time. This is a local page stored on my desktop referencing a bunch of local bmp files.

To throw some upper limit figures, both IE 10 and Chrome crashed with a page with 12,000 images.

Comment: I doubt it's a limit of HTML, but rather of the resources being used on the computer.  There's only so much active memory available.

Comment: Maybe, I have 38GB of RAM and when the page loads it definitely starts to slowly creep into the memory consumption but its topping out at like 13GB when starting at around 11GB or so.

Comment: The process might not be able to consume the full system RAM.  (For a whole host of good reasons, I imagine.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A limit to the number of img tags is not part of the HTML standard. Browser implementations like Chrome and IE may have some arbitrary limits, but it would not be part of the HTML standard. 12,000 images is quite a few to store in RAM, and that could be your issue.

If each image were 1 MB, and your opened 12,000, that would be about 12 GB of RAM right there. I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but HTML is not normally used for browser rendering of that size, that's supercomputing territory.

Comment: good distinction, the standard vs the implementation. If it was a standards limitation I could hound the implementors, but looks like I'll have to experiment with that figure empirically. I'll report what I come to when I get there.